# In spring boot my jpa model is validated against all schemas on the database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I just bumped my spring boot dependency from *2.1.8* to **2.2.0** and ran into this problem.

When I start up my spring boot application. I have setup jpa to validate the model against the database.

On my mariadb I have multiple schemas. I use one for each application I develop on.

My datasource url looks like this.
url: `jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/energyserviceschema?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useMysqlMetadata=true`

Before bumping the spring boot version the model was validated against the energyserviceschema and it worked. But now if I have other schemas with other tables it fails.

The funny thing is that its not really my model that causes the error cause it seems like jpa loads metadata from the database and then validates the schema Im using to see if the expected tables exist which they dont. And then it fails with this error.

Caused by:

> java.sql.SQLException: Table 'energyserviceschema.eventtable_sequence'
>   doesn't exist

But in my model I have no eventtable or eventtable_sequense. Thats in another proejct.

Have someone else had this issue when upgrading? Or should I have set the schemaname differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can define schema on `@Table` annnotation on your entity class.

```
@Table(name="table_name", schema="schema_name")
```

That should helps you

Comment: No that doesnt help. I found this bug https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16586 which points to this bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13373 which isnt fixed yet.
For me it didnt help to rollback my hibernate version to 5.4.0 I had to roll back to 5.3.10.FINAL then it disapeared. The easiest way to do this is to add a property in your pom file and define <hibernate.version>5.3.10.Final</hibernate.version> this will overrule the hibernate version in sprin gboot.